# Двусторонний SSL принцип, ключи и хранилища, keystore и truststore

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keystore, keytool

Прошу подсказать по теме. Вроде бы и гуглил, и находил материалы, и читал. Даже реализовывал вариант с самоподписанными сертификатами, тупо копируя примеры и подставляя свои значения, но, в голове от этого мало что прояснилось. 
Мог бы кто-нибудь объяснить по шагам, как придти к рабочему варианту к keystore и truststore?

Для того, чтобы было более понятно, о чем я прошу, я начну сам, а Вы, если что меня подправьте и дополните.

1. Создается хранилище и генерируется пара ключей: публичный и приватный
2. Создается csr-запрос на выпуск сертификата подписанного корневым
3. Выпущенный сертификат импортируется в keystore

Вопрос, на каком этапе происходит создание truststore и какие данные оно должно содержать? Куда помещать сам корневой сертификат?

Буду признателен за любые ответы.

Спасибо.

Comment: О какой системе речь. Java? Будьте добры добавить тег, иначе отвечающие могут пропустить ваш вопрос.

Comment: Да, спасибо, добавил пару тегов. Тут весь вопрос в самом механизме, принципе. Практическая реализация вторична. Но, например, такие задачи встречаются при работе с серверами приложений Tomcat, например, или в большей степени JBOSS WildFly

Comment: Но если уж говорить о конкретной реализации, то интересует генерирование при помощи keytool из Java